# matplotlib: plt.isinteractive() returns 0 instead of True or False after plt.ion() is called, when the script is being run in a terminal?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm, gnome-terminal

Here's my script:

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np

import matplotlib
print "matplotlib backend: {}".format(matplotlib.get_backend())

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import sys

print "-----------------------"
print "Is matplotlib plotting interactive? {}".format(plt.isinteractive())

if not plt.isinteractive():
    print "matplotlib plotting is not interactive..."
    print "Trying to set matplotlib plotting to be interactive..."
    plt.ion()

print "-----------------------"
print "Is matplotlib plotting interactive now? {}".format(plt.isinteractive())

continue_script = raw_input("Should script continue? [y/[n]]")
if continue_script.strip() != "y":
    sys.exit(0)

plt.draw()

continue_script = raw_input("Should script continue? [y/[n]]")
if continue_script.strip() != "y":
    sys.exit(0)
```

Surprisingly, when running the script in a terminal (`python interactive_plotting.py` -- preferably, I'd like to run it in PyCharm [hence the PyCharm tag], but I am having the same issue there, so I am just trying it in a plain `gnome-terminal` for now), I see the following output:

```
matplotlib backend: Qt4Agg
-----------------------
Is matplotlib plotting interactive? False
matplotlib plotting is not interactive...
Trying to set matplotlib plotting to be interactive...
-----------------------
Is matplotlib plotting interactive now? 0
-----------------------
Should script continue? [y/[n]]n #(I supply n as the response)
```

Note that `Qt4Agg` [is an interactive backend](http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend). Now, if I continue the script, then the subsequent `plt.draw()` command does not cause a figure to pop up.

If I just open a Python terminal and try things out, everything seems to work:

```
Python 2.7.9 |Anaconda 2.1.0 (64-bit)| (default, Mar  9 2015, 16:20:48) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://binstar.org
>>> from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
>>> plt.isinteractive()
False
>>> plt.ion()
>>> plt.isinteractive()
True
>>>
```

Subsequently running the `plt.draw()` command causes an empty figure to pop up, and I can type in additional commands in the terminal and see the figure updated on the fly. This is exactly what I want when running my script if I am not in a Python interpreter.

What's going on, and how can I get things to work?